# Admin user denied from database

Tags: mysql, access-denied

Im working on a website on my localhost, I was given a website, and have been asked to update it visually/code wise. I have a local copy of it, along with all of the database data but I seem to be getting an error trying to connect to it with an admin mysql account.

Here is the WAMP error im getting:

> Warning: mysql_pconnect() [function.mysql-pconnect]: Access denied for user 'temp'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in F:\wamp\www\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxxxxx.php on line 113

The password and username are correct and have full privileges.

Are there any logs that show the exact reason why it was denied? or has anyone had this occur to them as well?

cheers

Comment: pants down, show us your code baby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might have a "host" field mismatch between "localhost" and "127.0.0.1". MySQL distinguishes the two.

Try adding one more MySQL user: temp@127.0.0.1

Comment: this solved it!

wow thanks heaps man, I learn something new everyday haha

Answer (score 0):

logs should be in **C:\wamp\logs** assuming that your instalation is c:\wamp.

Can you connect via phpmyadmin ?